# Filter by multiple members of an hierarchy

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, dimensions, olap-cube

So lets say i have this MDX query:

```
select 
    NON EMPTY {([Dim 1].[Member 1].[Member 1])} on columns
    ,NON EMPTY {([Dim 2].[Member 2].[Member 1])} on rows
from [Cube 1]
where
{(
    [Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3]
    ,[Measures].[Measure 1]
)}
```

But now i also need to filter, as i did with **[Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3]**, but with several member values of an hierarchy from a different dimensionn, lets call them:

```
[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2]
[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 4]
[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 8]
```

I've tried this:

```
select 
    NON EMPTY {([Dim 1].[Member 1].[Member 1])} on columns
    ,NON EMPTY {([Dim 2].[Member 2].[Member 1])} on rows
from [Cube 1]
where
{(
    [Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3]
    ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2]
    ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 4]
    ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 8]
    ,[Measures].[Measure 1]
)}
```

Got this:

```
The 'Hierarchy 4' hierarchy appears more than once in the tuple.
```

Also tried this (i know, not much sense in here):

```
select 
    NON EMPTY {([Dim 1].[Member 1].[Member 1])} on columns
    ,NON EMPTY {([Dim 2].[Member 2].[Member 1])} on rows
from [Cube 1]
where
{(
    [Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3]
    ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2]
    :[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 4]
    :[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 8]
    ,[Measures].[Measure 1]
)}
```

And got this:

```
The : function expects a member expression for the 2 argument. A tuple set expression was used.
```

I'm fairly new to MDX (more experienced in T-SQL), don't even know what exactly to google, so bare with my dumbness.

Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the result that you expect? The basic problem you're running into is that the WHERE clause in MDX is not the same as SQL -- it is a "slicer" not a filter, allowing you to choose the definition of the cell values. With a bit of info about your expectation, it would be easier to show you an example that works for you. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the interest @findango. I expect exactly that, to slice, as i did with `[Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3]`, but also with multiple values of another hierarchy of another dimension: `[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2]`; `...&[Value 4]`; `...&[Value 8]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146047.aspx

> If you want to use multiple members from the same hierarchy, you need
>   to include a set in the WHERE clause

Another thing, in my example Dim 2 = Dim 3, so to get the result that i expect i need this:

```
select 
    NON EMPTY {([Dim 1].[Member 1].[Member 1])} on columns
    ,NON EMPTY 
       {(
          [Dim 2].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3] 
          ,[Dim 2].[Member 2].[Member 1]
       )} on rows
from [Cube 1]
where
(
    {
       [Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2]
       ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 4]
       ,[Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 8]
    }
    ,([Measures].[Measure 1])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [tuple](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/members.html) is badly formed; you can try a crossjoin (you need a set):

```
where
 { [Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 2], [Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 4], [Dim 4].[Hierarchy 4].[Member 4].&[Value 8] }  
 * {( [Dim 3].[Hierarchy 3].[Member 3].&[Value 3], [Measures].[Measure 1] )}
```

or you can use a [sub-query](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.html) instead (my favorite choice).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Marc Polizzi. But with this solution i kind of get the same error, only this time: **The 'Hierarchy 4' hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function.** I Should have mentioned i'm on SQL Server 2008 R2. The sub-query solution is totally new to me, could you please demonstrate it with my example?

Comment: sorry - missed the Hierarchy 3 ... fixed my response